# Stripe error : unable to perform color detection

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

im currently attempting to integrate Stripe into a little website.

I can see within Firebug, that this get request runs correctly

```
https://checkout.stripe.com/api/bootstrap?locale=en&key=******************
```

However another request comes back with a NetworkError : 400 Bad Request

```
https://checkout.stripe.com/api/color?image_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.*******.com%2Fassets%2Fimages%2Flayout-images%2Fstripe-logo.jpg&key=
```

The JSON response when opening the URL in a browser is

```
{
"error": {
"type": "invalid_request",
"message": "Unable to perform color detection."
}
}
```

some posts on the message indicate that it shouldnt be worried about. but I havent been able to find anything really informative on the specific error. Does anyon ehappen to know what is causing this error ?

Comment: I've started seeing this....however it is still possible to do the transaction. I think it should just be treated as a warning, rather than an error.

Answer (score 22):

This can happen if the image URL is not publicly accessible, as Stripe has to be able to request the image from their servers. This can happen if you are running a local copy of the application which isn't accessible from the outside world, or if it is behind a VPN or authentication.

Comment: I saw this when using a relative path to `image` and testing locally since Stripe is unable to resolve to `127.0.0.1/images/logo.png`. I changed to the  hosted path `https://www.domain.com/images/logo.png` and the problem was solved.

Comment: Any idea what Stripe uses this color for? After switching to a publicly accessible URL, I see a good value coming back from their service... but I don't see that color being used anywhere.

Comment: @Ghazgkull I would guess they use it to set the theme of the checkout widget to be similar to your logo/image if you don't specify a color explicitly. The other answer says if you specify it explicitly you won't have this issue.

Answer (score 12):

So I changed the handler to include another paramter of color and it appears to have resolved the issue.

```
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: '******************',
    image: '/assets/images/layout-images/stripe-logo.jpg',
    color: 'black',
    token: function(token) {
      // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
      // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
    }
  });
```

weird as im not quite sure why it wasnt included in the docs.

Comment: Thank you for this.. I was having a real wtf moment once I saw this in production.. this only happened for me once I decided to load the image from our Amazon S3 account

Comment: It seems adding a color no longer resolves the error

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error and setting color didn't work for me.
I changed the path of the image to the one given in Stripe documentation:

Changed

```
https://stripe.com/template/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png
```

to

```
https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png
```