# Unable to handle the stripe API in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-5.0

We're trying to perform load test on our local/internal website. we're facing issue at Stripe payment pop up. though handled the dynamic keys,it shows error as : "Unable to perform color detection".

Excellent if somebody can help me on this.

Tried with dynamic key's handling using regular expression extraction, using Jmeter 5.1 version tool.

Actual: Facing issue at stripe payment API, With error message as "Unable to perform color detection"

Expected: 200 status code.

Here's reference screenshot: 
[image: click here for image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Stripe error : unable to perform color detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786783/stripe-error-unable-to-perform-color-detection) question [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31433337/2897748)

> This can happen if the image URL is not publicly accessible, as Stripe has to be able to request the image from their servers. This can happen if you are running a local copy of the application which isn't accessible from the outside world, or if it is behind a VPN or authentication.

So you need to ask network administrator to allow your local application to access Stripe backend servers or alternatively ask developers to point the image to be obtained from local source.

There is nothing to do with JMeter here, you can only ignore the error by adding a [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved/) as a child of the request which is failing and ticking `Ignore Status` box

[image]